# Weed Identification

Tags: botany, species-identification

These are are weeds which grow on the silt of a lake, in India , climate is semi-tropical monsoonal
[image: first weed]

[image]

They dont look native probably exotic species. What are they?
Height is probably 1.5 feet.

Lake is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gobind_Sagar)

Comment: Is there any reason you don't believe they're native plants?

Comment: @Jude they are not found elsewhere except on lake bed everyear, moreover lake was constructed 50 yrs back ,

Comment: Please edit your question with the location (e.g. 1) what the lake name is, 2) what's the name of the river that drains into the lake, 3) the rough height of the plants). This would help a lot along with any other relevant details you can add.

Comment: Second one quite strongly  seems to be [*Xanthium strumarium*](http://www.flowersofindia.net/catalog/slides/Common%20Cocklebur.html) but the first (and foremost) one is confusing. Take a zoom close up of the inflorescence, if it contains small fruits (few mm) with 3 wedges  (looks like [*this*]) then it could be [*Rumex dentatus*](https://www.flowersofindia.net/catalog/slides/Toothed%20Dock.html)

Comment: @AlwaysConfused make this as answer

Comment: The first one looks similar to artemesia vulgaris, which grows in many places opportunistically in the south of europe. If you rub the seeds, do you get a very strange smell? if so it could be an artemesia. The second plant originated in America, the first plant from america to arive in the old world is Datura, for which the importation date is perhaps millenia old as similar to Datura in indian and chinese documents. It is an american solenacea related to tomatoes and datura.

Answer (score 1):

As Always confused already suggested, the second picture is [*Xanthium strumarium*](http://www.flowersofindia.net/catalog/slides/Common%20Cocklebur.html).
This is a very variable species, and there is a lot of debate around splitting this species into (sub)species. There is a possibility this is plant belongs to one of the few accepted species that [wikipedia lists](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanthium), some even native to Eastern Asia. However, I can't verify this because pictures of these are scarce.

But from my personal field expierence, this plant looks exactly like the X. strumarium and the habitat also matches, so I am comfortable to call this X. strumarium.

As to your first plant:
- It will be hard to say without a close-up of the flowers/seeds.
- It would be better to ask only one plant per question, so please remove it here and ask a new question.